# Вставка содержимого содержимого внутри родительского блока при клике по дочернему

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть последовательно расположенные родительские блоки, внутри каждого из них есть дочерний. Нужно чтобы при клике по дочернему внутри его родителя вставлялся еще один блок. Пробовал вот так, если не трудно, покажите рабочую версию на моем примере.

```js
$('.bottom').click(function(){
    var container = document.getElementById(".add-to-cart-form");
    var div = document.createElement("div.throbber");
    container.appendChild(div);
});
```

```css
.throbber{
  display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-to-cart-form">
  
<div class="bottom">
  Вставить блок
</div>
</div>
<div class="add-to-cart-form">
  
<div class="bottom">
  Вставить блок
</div>
</div>
<div class="add-to-cart-form">
  
<div class="bottom">
  Вставить блок
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.bottom').click(function(){
  var container = $(this).closest(".add-to-cart-form");
  container.append("<div class='throbber'></div>");
});
```